# Time calculation on mobile devices

Tags: android, mobile, time

I want to calculate time difference between the last event on the device and the current. But the user can always change the time manually by setting the system time, so the difference can be different from the real time. Is there a way to calculate time difference that is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `System.nanoTime()` between the two periods, then subtract. Unlike `System.currentTimeMillis()` which changes when the user changes the device time, `System.nanoTime()` will not be affected.

> Returns the current value of the most precise available system timer,
>   in nanoseconds.
>
> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and **is not
>   related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time**. The value
>   returned **represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time**
>   (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). This method
>   provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond
>   accuracy. No guarantees are made about how frequently values change.
>   Differences in successive calls that span greater than approximately
>   292 years (263 nanoseconds) will not accurately compute elapsed time
>   due to numerical overflow.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String time1 = "22:55:00";
String time2 = "23:05:00";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date1 = format.parse(time1);
Date date2 = format.parse(time2);
long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SystemClock.uptimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis%28%29)

I use the following code to achieve near-constant FPS in my game:

```
long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), then = this.then, actualSleep;
        actualSleep = DT - ((now < then) ? (Long.MAX_VALUE - then) + now : now - then);
        Thread.sleep((actualSleep < 0) ? 0 : actualSleep);
```